# Add images to Google Spreadsheet via Google Apps Script

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to add images to the spreadsheet with Google App Script?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the URL of the image, you can use the [IMAGE formula](http://www.labnol.org/internet/images-in-google-spreadsheet/18167/) to insert that image into any cell via Apps Script

```
 SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSheet()
  .getRange(1,1);
  .setValue('=IMAGE("http://img.labnol.org/di/high-quality-photo.jpg")');
```

Comment: You may please accept the answer if it solved your problem.